# Create a column value based on a matching regular expression

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe, matching

I have the following character string in a column called "Sentences" for a `df`:

`I like an apple`

I would like to create a second column, called `Type`, whose values are determined by matching strings. I would like to take the regular expression `\bapple\b`, match it with the sentence and if it matches, add the value `Fruit_apple` in the `Type` column.

In the long run I'd like to do this with several other strings and types.

Is there an easy way to do this using a function?

dataset (survey_1):

```
structure(list(slider_8.response = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 2L
), Sentences = c("He might could do it.", "I ever see the film.", 
"I may manage to come visit soon.", "She’ll never be forgotten.", 
"They might find something special.", "It might not be a good buy.", 
"Maybe my pain will went away.", "Stephen maybe should fix your bicycle.", 
"It used to didnʼt matter if you walked in late.", "He’d could climb the stairs.", 
"Only Graeme would might notice that.", "I used to cycle a lot. ", 
"Your dad belongs to disagree with this. ", "We can were pleased to see her.", 
"He may should take us to the city.", "I could never forgot his deep voice.", 
"I should can turn this thing over to Ann.", "They must knew who they really are.", 
"We used to runs down three flights.", "I don’t care what he may be up to. ", 
"That’s something I ain’t know about.", "That must be quite a skill.", 
"We must be able to invite Jim.", "She used to play with a trolley.", 
"He is done gone. ", "You might can check this before making a decision.", 
"It would have a positive effect on the team. ", "Ruth can maybe look for it later.", 
"You should tag along at the dance.", "They’re finna leave town.", 
"A poem should looks like that.", "I can tell you didn’t do your homework. ", 
"I can driving now.", "They should be able to put a blanket over it.", 
"We could scarcely see each other.", "I might says I was never good at maths.", 
"The next dance will be a quickstep. ", "I might be able to find myself a seat in this place.", 
"Andrew thinks we shouldn’t do it.", "Jack could give a hand.", 
"She’ll be able to come to the event.", "She’d maybe keep the car the way it is.", 
"Sarah used to be able to agree with this proposal.", "I’d like to see your lights working. ", 
"I’d be able to get a little bit more sleep.", "John may has a second name.", 
"You must can apply for this job.", "I maybe could wait till the 8 o’clock train.", 
"She used to could go if she finished early.", "That would meaned something else, eh?", 
"You’ll can enjoy your holiday.", "We liketa drowned that day. ", 
"I must say it’s a nice feeling.", "I eaten my lunch."), construct = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 54L), class = "data.frame")
```

type_list:

```
list("DM_will_can"=c("ll can","will can"), "DM_would_could"=c("d could","would could"),
                  "DM_might_can"="might can","DM_might_could"="might could","DM_used_to_could"="used to could",
                  "DM_should_can"="should can","DM_would_might"=c("d might", "would might"),"DM_may_should"="may should",
                  "DM_must_can"="must can", "SP_will_be_able"=c("ll be able","will be able"),
                  "SP_would_be_able"=c("d be able","would be able"),"SP_might_be_able"="might be able",
                  "SP_maybe_could"="maybe could","SP_used_to_be_able"="used to be able","SP_should_be_able"=
                    "should be able","SP_would_maybe"=c("d maybe", "would maybe"), "SP_maybe_should"="maybe should",
                  "SP_must_be_able"="must be able", "Filler_will_a"="quickstep","Filler_will_b"="forgotten",
                  "Filler_would_a"="lights working","Filler_would_b"="positive effect","Filler_can_a"="homework",
                  "Filler_can_b"="Ruth","Filler_could_a"="scarcely","Filler_could_b"="Jack", "Filler_may_a"="may be up to",
                  "Filler_may_b"="visit soon", "Filler_might_a"="good buy","Filler_might_be"="something special",
                  "Filler_should_a"="tag along","Filler_should_b"="Andrew","Filler_used_to_a"="trolley",
                  "Filler_used_to_b"="cycle a lot","Filler_must_a"="quite a skill","Filler_must_b"="nice feeling",
                  "Dist_gram_will_went"="will went","Dist_gram_meaned"="meaned","Dist_gram_can_were"="can were",
                  "Dist_gram_forgot"="never forgot", "Dist_gram_may_has"="may has", 
                  "Dist_gram_might_says"="might says","Dist_gram_used_to_runs"="used to runs",
                  "Dist_gram_should_looks"="should looks","Dist_gram_must_knew"="must knew","Dist_dial_liketa"="liketa",
                  "Dist_dial_belongs"="belongs to disagree","Dist_dial_finna"="finna","Dist_dial_used_to_didnt"="used to didn't matter",
                  "Dist_dial_eaten"="I eaten", "Dist_dial_can_driving"="can driving","Dist_dial_aint_know"="That's something",
                  "Dist_dial_ever_see"="ever see the film","Dist_dial_done_gone"="done gone")
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this. The sensible type and level of abstraction depends on what you expect the types to be and how many matching strings per type, i.e. it is difficult to answer this question without quite a lot more information.

Comment: Sorry, I realise my question is a bit vague. I will try to elaborate. I will have a finite number of ```Sentences``` to annotate, with 54 different ```Type``` levels and a maximum of 2 matching strings per ```Type``` level. 

I am basically trying to automate the annotation process rather than doing it by hand for each sentence. Does this make my question a bit clearer? All best, Cameron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to do this with a Python dictionary, but we're talking about R, so I've more or less translated the approach. There is probably a more idiomatic way to do this in R than two `for` loops, but this should work:

```r
# Define data
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1:5),
    sentences = c("I like apples", "I like dogs", "I have cats", "Dogs are cute", "I like fish")
)

#   id     sentences
# 1  1 I like apples
# 2  2   I like dogs
# 3  3   I have cats
# 4  4 Dogs are cute
# 5  5   I like fish

type_list <- list(
    "fruit" = c("apples", "oranges"),
    "animals" = c("dogs", "cats")
)

types <- names(type_list)

df$type <- NA
df$item <- NA

for (type in types) {
    for (item in type_list[[type]]) {
        matches <- grep(item, df$sentences, ignore.case = TRUE)
        df[matches, "type"]  = type
        df[matches, "item"]  = item
    }
}


# Output:
#   id     sentences    type   item
# 1  1 I like apples   fruit apples
# 2  2   I like dogs animals   dogs
# 3  3   I have cats animals   cats
# 4  4 Dogs are cute animals   dogs
# 5  5   I like fish    <NA>   <NA>
```

**EDIT**

Added after data was added. If I read in your data, and call it `df`, and your type list and call it `type_list`, the following works:

```r
types <- names(type_list)

df$type <- NA
df$item <- NA

for (type in types) {
    for (item in type_list[[type]]) {
        matches <- grep(item, df$Sentences, ignore.case = TRUE)
        df[matches, "type"]  = type
        df[matches, "item"]  = item
    }
}
```

This is exactly the same as my previous code, except `Sentences` has an upper case S in your data frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam. Adapting this to my data and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: No problem - I have updated it slightly to create NA columns rather than empty character vectors. Not sure why I did it the other way,  it's definitely worse.

Comment: Hi Sam, I ran into a couple of issues while adapting your code. I edited my post to show you the datasets I am dealing with. I think I made a mistake in the for loop, do you know what might be causing it ?

Comment: I can't see any edits to your original post.

Comment: Yes I am struggling to make edits, the editor is refusing to let me save them because of code formatting issues.

Comment: Just added my datasets. And here is the loop I used (couldn't add it in my post): for loop code: 

types <- names(type_list)
for (construct in types) {
    matches <- grep(construct, survey_1$Sentences, ignore.case = TRUE)
    survey_1[matches, "construct"]  = construct
  }

Comment: Right - the difference now you've posted your sample data is that I've used a named list `"fruit" = c("apples", "oranges")`, and you haven't, i.e. you don't have items as well as types. The code won't work unless the input is in the same format.

Comment: Yes, I was anticipating that and thought deleting a layer of code from the loop might help, but it doesn't.  I followed the same format as you for the list but I don't have types and items - just one-level types and the string variants that correspond to each. Does that require rewriting the type list and the for loop?

Comment: Just realised that I didn't give you the right ```type_list``` structure in my edits. Just changed that again, sorry for confusion.

Comment: See my edit - only difference I can see is that `Sentences` has an upper case S.

Comment: Yes was about to tell you I managed to make it work perfectly. Thank you very much for your patience!

Comment: Glad it worked!